# Grails: Create dynamic SQL-Connection

Tags: sql, grails, groovy, grails-orm

For my application I need dynamic database connections at runtime. 
I know, there are ways to create multiple datasources but they are not that dynamically I think. 
Scenario:

A user can enter database credentials and connect to a remote database  to import single rows and tables to an other database. For this purpose I need to connect to the remote database dynamically.

I've tried to do that in a service like they've said in [If I use groovy sql class in grails, does it use the grails connection pooling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322217/if-i-use-groovy-sql-class-in-grails-does-it-use-the-grails-connection-pooling)

Note: GORM is dispensable in this case, I can use plain SQL instead.

Any ideas? Thank you..

Edit: Grails 2.3.4

Comment: What version of Grails?  Also do these datasources need to persist over multiple calls, or do you just need to connect, grab some data and disconnect?

Comment: @tim_yates It's Grails 2.3.4. Ideal solution would be if I could do multiple calls. If it's not possible the easier solution would be enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing to register DataSource beans at runtime:

Given a Grails Service:

```
package whatever

import groovy.sql.Sql
import org.springframework.context.*
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext

class DataSourceService implements ApplicationContextAware {

    ApplicationContext  applicationContext

    def registerBean( String beanName, String dsurl, String uid, String pwd ) {
        if( !applicationContext.containsBean( beanName ) ) {
            def bb = new grails.spring.BeanBuilder()
            bb.beans {
                "$beanName"( DataSource ) {
                    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                    url             = dsurl
                    username        = uid
                    password        = pwd
                    validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                    testOnBorrow    = true
                    maxActive       = 1
                    maxIdle         = 1
                    minIdle         = 1
                    initialSize     = 1
                }
            }
            bb.registerBeans( applicationContext )
            log.info "Added $beanName"
        }
        else {
            log.error "Already got a bean called $beanName"
        }
    }

    def deRegisterBean( String beanName ) {
        if( applicationContext.containsBean( beanName ) ) {
            (applicationContext as GenericApplicationContext).removeBeanDefinition( beanName )
            log.info "Removed $beanName"
        }
        else {
            log.error "Trying to deRegister a bean $beanName that I don't know about"
        }
    }

    def getSql( String beanName ) {
        Sql.newInstance( applicationContext.getBean( beanName ) )
    }
}
```

Then, you should be able to call the service to register a new datasource:

```
dataSourceService.registerBean( 'myDS', 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql', 'test', 'test' )
```

Get a Groovy Sql object for it:

```
dataSourceService.getSql( 'myDS' ).rows( 'SELECT * FROM whatever' )
```

And remove the bean when done

```
dataSourceService.deRegisterBean( 'myDS' )
```

Fingers crossed...  I've yanked that code from a project of mine and changed/not-tested it ;-)

### Update

The [runtime-datasources](https://github.com/domurtag/runtime-datasources) plugin has been created which uses the approach outlined in this post to allow datasources to be added/removed at runtime.

Comment: Looks great! I only get the problem "Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@75c65470 returned null for URL:null" when I call the select. Thank you.

Comment: @n33dle try that, I changed the url parameter to be called `dsurl` in the `registerBean` method

Comment: @n33dle glad to help :-)  Have fun!

Comment: Hi, is there any way to use the newly create dataSource as a GORM dataSource, in order to run `Domain.myDS.list()` ? Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321878/grails-changing-datasource-url-at-runtime-to-achieve-multi-tenant-database-sepa

Comment: @tim_yates have you considered releasing this as a plugin?

Comment: @Dónal not until now... ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates if you don't have the time/motivation, do you mind if I do it?

Comment: @Dónal Not at all, go for it :-)

Comment: @tim_yates thanks, you will of course be given the deserved credit

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have the JDBC drivers for all the datasources on your classpath, you can create an instance of `groovy.sql.Sql` that will connect to whatever database you like, e.g.

```
Sql sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB', 'sa', 'myPassword', 
    'org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver')

// now use the Sql instance to execute a query, or whatever....
```

Comment: I've tried that with def conn = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "test", "test", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") but I always get 'No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql'. Dependency is loaded in BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the MySQL JDBC driver on your classpath, can you show the relevant section of `BuildConfig.groovy`?

Comment: dependencies {
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
    }