# Catch startup exception in Grails if Hibernate database connection fails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

We're building an app using Grails 2.0.4, GORM, and Hibernate. When the database is not available, Grails will not initialize, and startup fails. We thought our pool settings would protect against startup failures, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

If pool settings alone can't address this, is it possible to catch exceptions in `resources.groovy` where, if a database service can't be initialized, switch to a file-based service temporarily? Something like this...

**resources.groovy**

```
try{

   myDataService(PostgresDatabaseServiceImpl){}

}catch(Exception e){
   //if database connect failed, use local service instead
   myDataService(FileBasedServiceImpl){}
}
```

Even if the above is possible, it creates a new problem; how to switch back, dynamically, once the database *is* available. We attempted the above try/catch, but it had no impact, the startup issue persists:

> Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor':
>   Initialization of bean failed

If it's possible to avoid startup failures through pool settings alone, we could certainly manage SQL exceptions at runtime when the app attempts to use bad database connections, but startup failures we can't manage.

**DataSource.groovy (pool settings)**

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    properties {
       maxActive = 20
       minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
       timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
       numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
       testOnBorrow=true
       testWhileIdle=true
       testOnReturn=true
       validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    }
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = false
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> We attempted the above try/catch, but it had no impact, the startup issue persists:

So it seems you already have the answer to the question of whether it's possible to register a Spring bean for a (potentially) unavailable database in `resources.groovy`.

As an alternative, you could try registering a Spring bean for the database at runtime. This advantage of this approach is that even if registering the bean fails, you will be able to catch the error and use the file-based service instead. An example of how to register DataSource beans at runtime is [show here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20634968/2648).

To use this approach, register only a bean for the file-based service in `resources.groovy`

```
myDataService(FileBasedServiceImpl)
```

Then when you need to access the datasource:

```
class DataSourceService implements ApplicationContextAware {

  def myDataService
  ApplicationContext applicationContext

  private static PG_BEAN = 'postgres'

  def getDataSource() {

    try {
      getPostgresService()

    } catch (ex) {
      myDataService
    }
  }

  private getPostgresService() {
    def postgres

    if (applicationContext.containsBean(PG_BEAN)) {
      postgres = applicationContext.getBean(PG_BEAN)

    } else {
      // register a bean under the name 'postGres' and store a reference to it in postgres
      // https://stackoverflow.com/a/20634968/2648
    }            

    checkPostgres(postgres)
  }

  private checkPostres(postgresBean) {
    // check that the database is available, throw an exception if it's not, return 
    // postgresBean if it is
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, and should address my issue, will try it out,

Comment: This is old by now, but I'd be interested in hearing how it worked out.