# Grails: changing dataSource url at runtime to achieve multi tenant database separation

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi tenant application with Grails and I want to keep separate databases.
I need to change the url dynamically at runtime to point GORM to different database.

I have a front-end acting as a balancer distributing requests to a cluster of backend hosts. Each backend host runs a Grails 2.3.5 instance and a mysql-server with several databases (one per tenant). I would like to change dataSource dynamically so that GORM can access domain entities on the right database.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: I [found this](http://sourceforge.net/p/grailsdds/code/HEAD/tree/) but it seems abandoned

Answer (score 1):

You can configure multiple data source in your DataSource.groovy, have a look in the [blog](http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/configure-multiple-datasources-in-grails/).

In your domains: add which data source your domain can interact, eg.,

```
static mapping = {
    datasources(['dataSource1', 'dataSource2'])
}
```

or "ALL" for all datasources, eg.,

```
static mapping = {
    datasource 'ALL'
}
```

and then you can make queries with data source name to which you want to get/set data, eg.,

```
def userClass = User.class
User user = userClass.dataSource1.findByName('username')
```

Ref:- [multipleDatasources](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources), [Querying on multiple datasource in grails](http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/querying-on-multiple-datasource-in-grails/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not going to work, because dataSources will be added at runtime as new users subscribe. So I can't preconfigure them in the DataSource.groovy...

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634276/grails-create-dynamic-sql-connection?sfb=2

Comment: I already found that link but while it works, it doesn't allow to use the newly created dataSource as a GORM dataSource. So it is not possible to run `Domain.myDS.list()` for example...

Comment: I have worked with the approach I have posted above and I know `Domain.myDs.list()` works there. But I have never tried the way as posted as answer in the link I pasted above in the comment, so I have no idea how to query in that scenario.

Comment: @user1690588 ..is it possible to set this data-source  at central place instead of setting for each domain object at runtime?

Comment: @Vish - I don't think this is possible. If you have mentioned multiple datasource in the mapping closure then you have to mention datasource while queering on domain.

Comment: thanks.. is there any option for dynamic linking of datasources

Comment: @Vish - No, run-time datasource configuration not supported. :-(

Comment: @user1690588:will this approach work with gorm queries

Comment: I haven't tried all the queries. I have tried criteria, HQL, dynamic finders, get. All these are working. But named queries are not working.