# How to dynamically set data source at run time in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

If I have two dataSources:  `dataSource_1` and  `dataSource_2`. How do I at runtime set datasource based on conditions -such as who logged in?

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource_1 {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb"
        }
        dataSource_2 {
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
            driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
            username = 'lookup'
            password = 'secret'
            url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/lookup'
            dbCreate = 'update'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails: changing dataSource url at runtime to achieve multi tenant database separation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321878/grails-changing-datasource-url-at-runtime-to-achieve-multi-tenant-database-sepa)

Comment: That's not what I asked at at . Please don't write on top of my post to indicate this was asked before.

Comment: try this :- http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources

Comment: @johnsam any solution for same..i am facing similar problem